# Failed while connecting to databricks using databricks connect V2

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect, databricks-unity-catalog

I'm trying to connect to DataBricks workspace from my local machine using DataBricks-Connect v2. I have configured the DataBricks workspace with unity catalog and configured my local machine with DataBricks connect v2 using Access token authentication. I'm getting below error when I tried running the application I'm getting below error.

**Error:**
[image]

```
from databricks.connect import DatabricksSession as SparkSession
from databricks.sdk.core import Config
config = Config(profile="DEFAULT", cluster_id="xxxxx-yyyyyy-0987654321")
spark = SparkSession.builder.sdkConfig(config=config).getOrCreate()
spark.range(10).collect()
```

Comment: Provide the code you are trying.